# Date Format in laravel

Tags: laravel, date-format

I try to validate a POST request.
The format is:

```
public function setDateDebutAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date_debut'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('panel.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d') : null;
    }
```

I get this error message:
date debut IS NOT in format d-m-Y.te format

How can I change the date format in `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: what is the value of  config('panel.date_format') and $value

Comment: You can also do something like `$value ? date(config('panel.date_format'),strtotime($value)) : null;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think it's work.

```
public function setDateDebutAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date_debut'] = $value ? Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y') : null;
    }
```